# Jquery onclick event with angular datatable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I have to open a new link whenever a column of datatable is clicked. Here's my datatable code which is fetching data through ajax call-

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="featuretable row-border compact hover" >
   <thead >
      <!--change style of column with css-->
      <tr>
         <th class="Header">Feature</th>
         <th class="Header">ID</th>
         <th class="Header">Log</th>
         <th class="Header">Location</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Here's my Jquery Code i was trying -

```
$('.featuretable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log(table.row(this).data());
    var data = table.row(this).data();
    alert('You clicked on ' + data[1] + '\'s row');
});
```

The css file reads-

```
.Header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #6f7277;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #4b4a4a;
    overflow: hidden;
}

table.featuretable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table.featuretable td,
th {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 30px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

table.featuretable th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: :middle;
}

table.featuretable td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: :middle;
}

table.featuretable tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background: #f3f7fb;
}

table.featuretable tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

on click , chrome is giving the error "ReferenceError: table is not defined" . Anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: can you give me some more information about the `table` class you're using? I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: I've added the css code now.

Comment: My bad. I was talking about the js `table` class you try to use at `console.log( table.row( this ).data() );`. Is it part of the datatables? Or do you define it earlier?

Comment: Nope. That's the part where i'm wrong. In jquery we usually define (#table).datatable, which then works but In angular all we have to do is say datatable in the table tag. In short, no I haven't defined table class. Table.row is just supposed to be a jquery function.

Comment: Looking at your code, you are referencing "table". Where is this defined? We probably need to see more of your JS code, or make a jsbin/plunkr.

Comment: I think i didn't define it. Should it not reference the table class featuretable? else , could you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: ok, so I have to ask. Why are you trying to mix jQuery and AngularJS? Can't you implement the desired logic within AngularJS? Maybe using a directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the angular dataTables directives you should define a `dtInstance` and work on that instead :

```js
$scope.dtInstance = {}
```

```html
<table datatable="" dt-instance="dtInstance" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="featuretable row-border compact hover" >
```

Then in your jQuery event handler, use `dtInstance` as the table reference

```js
$('.featuretable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
   var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row( this ).data();
   alert( 'You clicked on '+data[1]+'\'s row' );
} );
```